# TypeScript React Hooks, custom hook type inference issue

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

So I have this custom hook to decode a token

```
export function useToken(initial: string) {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string>(initial)
  const [decoded, setDecoded] = useState<Token>()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (token) {
      const value = decodeToken(token)
      if (isTokenExpired(value)) {
        setDecoded(undefined)
      } else {
        setDecoded(value)
      }
    } else {
      setDecoded(undefined)
    }
  }, [token])

  return [decoded, setToken]
}
```

The return type looks good, here a

```
[Token, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>]
```

I have another hook that uses this hook, but it's seeing the return type incorrectly

```
export function useUser() {
  const [decoded, setToken] = useToken(getTokenFromStorage())
  //...
```

Here useToken gives both decoded and setToken the same type of

```
Token | React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
```

i.e.

```
decoded: Token | React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>, setToken: Token | React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
```

What am I doing wrong...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to use "as const" at the end of the return. This is resolve issue.

```js
return [decoded, setToken] as const
```

for more info check "[const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)"

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue the other day!

You have to be explicit with the return type, as Typescript isn't inferring the type correctly.

For example:

```
export function useToken(initial: string): [Token, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>] {
}
```

That should fix it... I think it is a typescript bug so probably an issue needs to be made for it.